# Making an OpenMP program work with Pthreads, segfault error

Tags: c, parallel-processing, pthreads, openmp

I have a written a program that performs Gaussian elimination in C and returns the L2 norm of a matrix. The program is called like `./exec n k` where `n` is the size of a n by n matrix and k is the number of threads that will be used to do the program (max 4). I allocate space for a n by n+1 matrix because having an augmented matrix is part of the gaussian elimination.

It works perfectly in OpenMP. As seen in the code below, I only have 1 parallel for. My goal now is to make that parallel for loop run concurrently using Pthreads instead of OpenMP. I made the for loop that be parallelized into a separate function and create pthreads to deal with it. My guess is that the pthreads are not each doing a different part of the loop (basically a different iteration of j), but instead the 4 Pthreads are just running the entire loops. I run the program like `./gauss 30 4` and it sometimes work and sometimes segfaults, although when it does work the L2 norm is not 0 (L2 will return 0 if program worked perfectly), so something is obviously up with the threading section. When I run it through GDB it segfaults at a loop for some reason but this same loop runs perfectly in OpenMP...can someone help me out

GDB

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V99yt.png

OpenMP Code:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <omp.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>
    //globals
    double **a, *vect, *bvect, scalar, ratio, sum, delta, *temp;
    int i,j,k,ptr, z;
    int y,z;
    int bvectcount = 0;
    struct timeval start, end;
    // a is matrix, b is vector, x is the solution vector, and n is the size 
    double L2(double **a, double *bvect, double *vect, int matrixSize) {
        double sum;
        double res[matrixSize];
        int i, j;
        for (i=0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
            sum = (double) 0;
            for (j=0; j < matrixSize; j++) {
                sum += a[i][j] * vect[j];
            }
            res[i] = sum;
        }
        for (i=0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
            res[i] -= vect[i];
        }
        double sum_squares = (double) 0;
        for (i=0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
            sum_squares += res[i] * res[i];
        }
        return sqrt(sum_squares);
    }
    int checkargs(int argc, char* argv[]){
        if(argc != 3){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Usage is size threadNum\n" );
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        //check for args
        checkargs(argc, argv);
        int matrixSize = atoi(argv[1]);
        int threadNum = atoi(argv[2]);
        int chunk = matrixSize/threadNum;
        //memory allocation
        a = (double**)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double*));
        for(i = 0; i < matrixSize ; i++)
            a[i] = (double*)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double) * matrixSize);
        vect = (double*)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double));
        bvect = (double*)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double));
        temp = (double*)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double));
        for(i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i){
            for(j = 0; j < matrixSize + 1; ++j){
                a[i][j] = drand48(); 
            }
        }   
        j = 0;
        j += matrixSize;
        for(i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i){
            bvect[i] = a[i][j];
        }
        //generation of scalar matrix (diagonal vector)
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
        for(i=0; i<matrixSize; i++){
            scalar = a[i][i];
            //initialization of p to travel throughout matrix
            ptr = i;
            //find largest number in column and row number of it
            for(k = i+1; k < matrixSize; k++){
            if(fabs(scalar) < fabs(a[k][i])){
                //k is row of scalar, while
               scalar = a[k][i];
               ptr = k;
            }
        }
        //swaping the elements of diagonal row and row containing largest no
        for(j = 0; j <= matrixSize; j++){
            temp[0] = a[i][j];
            a[i][j]= a[ptr][j];
            a[ptr][j] = temp[0];
        }
        //calculating triangular matrix
        //threading needs to be done HERE
        ratio = a[i][i];
        for(k = 0; k < matrixSize + 1; k++){
            a[i][k] = a[i][k] / ratio;
        }
        double temp2;
        #pragma omp parallel default(none) num_threads(threadNum)  shared(a,i,matrixSize,vect) private(j,z,ratio,temp2)
        {
        #pragma omp for schedule(static)
        for(j = i + 1; j<matrixSize; j++){
            temp2 = a[j][i]/a[i][i];
            for(z = 0; z<matrixSize + 1; z++){
                a[j][z] = a[j][z] - temp2 * a[i][z];
                }
            }
        }
    }
        //backward substitution method
        for(i=matrixSize-1; i >=0; i--){
            for(k = i; k > 0; k--){
                a[k-1][matrixSize] -= a[k-1][i] * a[i][matrixSize];
                a[k-1][i] -= a[k-1][i] * a[i][i];
            }     
        }
        for(i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i){
            vect[i] = a[i][matrixSize];
        }
        double l2Norm;
        l2Norm = L2(a, bvect, vect, matrixSize);
        printf("THIS IS L2 NORM: %f\n", l2Norm);
        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
        delta = ((end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec) * 1000000u + 
             end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1.e6;
        printf("end time: %f\n", delta);
    }
```

Pthreads code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//globals
double **a, *vect, *bvect, scalar, ratio, sum, delta, *temp;
int i,j,k,ptr, z;
int y,z;
int bvectcount = 0;
int threadcount;
pthread_t workerThreads[4];
typedef struct threader {
    int counter;
    int matrixl;
} threader;
struct timeval start, end;
    void *retval;

int checkargs(int argc, char* argv[]);
// a is matrix, b is vector, x is the solution vector, and n is the size 
double L2(double **a, double *bvect, double *vect, int matrixSize) {
    double sum;
    double res[matrixSize];
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        sum = (double) 0;
        for (j=0; j < matrixSize; j++) {
            sum += a[i][j] * vect[j];
        }
        res[i] = sum;
    }
    for (i=0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        res[i] -= vect[i];
    }
    double squaresum = (double) 0;
    for (i=0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        squaresum += res[i] * res[i];
    }
    return sqrt(squaresum);
}
int checkargs(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc != 3){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Usage is size threadNum\n" );
        exit(1);
    }
}

void *parallelstuff(void *args){
    threader temp = *((threader *)args);
    int i, matrixSize;
    i = temp.counter;
    matrixSize = temp.matrixl;
    double temp2;
    for(j = i + 1; j<matrixSize; j++){
        temp2 = a[j][i]/a[i][i];
        for(z = 0; z<matrixSize + 1; z++){
            a[j][z] = a[j][z] - temp2 * a[i][z];
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    //check for args
    checkargs(argc, argv);
    int matrixSize = atoi(argv[1]);
    int threadNum = atoi(argv[2]);
    //memory allocation
    a = (double**)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double*));
    for(i = 0; i < matrixSize ; i++)
        a[i] = (double*)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double) * matrixSize);
    vect = (double*)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double));
    bvect = (double*)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double));
    temp = (double*)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double));
    for(i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < matrixSize + 1; ++j){
            a[i][j] = drand48(); 
        }
    }
    j = 0;
    j += matrixSize;
    for(i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i){
        bvect[i] = a[i][j];
    }
//generation of scalar matrix (diagonal vector)
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    for(i=0; i<matrixSize; i++){
        scalar = a[i][i];
    //initialization of p to travel throughout matrix
        ptr = i;
    //find largest number in column and row number of it
        for(k = i+1; k < matrixSize; k++){
        if(fabs(scalar) < fabs(a[k][i])){
            //k is row of scalar, while
           scalar = a[k][i];
           ptr = k;
        }
    }
    //swaping the elements of diagonal row and row containing largest no
    for(j = 0; j <= matrixSize; j++)
    {
        temp[0] = a[i][j];
        a[i][j]= a[ptr][j];
        a[ptr][j] = temp[0];
    }
    ratio = a[i][i];
    for(k = 0; k < matrixSize + 1; k++){
        a[i][k] = a[i][k] / ratio;
    }   
    threader stuff;
    stuff.counter = i;
    stuff.matrixl = matrixSize;
    //MAKE EACH THREAD DO SOMETHING DIFF
    // parallelstuff(int i, int matrixSize, double **a){
    for(threadcount = 0; threadcount < threadNum; threadcount++){
        if(pthread_create (&workerThreads[threadcount], NULL, parallelstuff, (void *) &stuff ) != 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: consumer create problem\n");
            exit(1);
            }
        }
    while(threadcount != 0){
        if(pthread_join (workerThreads[threadcount-1], &retval ) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: consumer create problem\n");
        exit(1);
        }
        threadcount--;
    }

    //create matrix of n size 
    //backward substitution method
    for(i=matrixSize-1; i >=0; i--){
        for(k = i; k > 0; k--){
            a[k-1][matrixSize] -= a[k-1][i] * a[i][matrixSize];
            a[k-1][i] -= a[k-1][i] * a[i][i];
        }  
    }
    for(i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i){
        vect[i] = a[i][matrixSize];
        }       
    double l2Norm;
    l2Norm = L2(a, bvect, vect, matrixSize);
    printf("THIS IS L2 NORM: %f\n", l2Norm);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    delta = ((end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec) * 1000000u + 
         end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1.e6;
    printf("end time: %f\n", delta);
}
        }
```

Comment: You're accessing the global `double **a` in `parallelstuff()`, both reading and writing to it. I see no synchronisation. If these accesses are neither atomic nor synchronized, they may exhibit race conditions, thus undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

note that `j , z` should be declared as local (private) variables in each thread.
in OpenMP Code , you closed the brace of for loop in line 100 :

```
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    for(i=0; i<matrixSize; i++){
        scalar = a[i][i];
        //initialization of p to travel throughout matrix
        .......
        ......
        .....

} //line 100
```

but in pthreads code, you closed it in line 149, so the full code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//globals
double **a, *vect, *bvect, scalar, ratio, sum, delta, *temp;
int i,j,k,ptr, z;
int y; //z?
int bvectcount = 0;
int threadcount;
pthread_t workerThreads[4];
typedef struct threader {
    int counter;
    int matrixl;
} threader;
struct timeval start, end;
    void *retval;

int checkargs(int argc, char* argv[]);
// a is matrix, b is vector, x is the solution vector, and n is the size 
double L2(double **a, double *bvect, double *vect, int matrixSize) {
    double sum;
    double res[matrixSize];
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        sum = (double) 0;
        for (j=0; j < matrixSize; j++) {
            sum += a[i][j] * vect[j];
        }
        res[i] = sum;
    }
    for (i=0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        res[i] -= vect[i];
    }
    double squaresum = (double) 0;
    for (i=0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        squaresum += res[i] * res[i];
    }
    return sqrt(squaresum);
}
int checkargs(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc != 3){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Usage is size threadNum\n" );
        exit(1);
    }
}

void *parallelstuff(void *args){
    threader temp = *((threader *)args);
    int i, matrixSize;
    i = temp.counter;
    matrixSize = temp.matrixl;
    //printf("matrixSize=%d counter=%d\n" , matrixSize ,temp.counter );
    double temp2;
    int j , z; //houssam
    for(j = i + 1; j<matrixSize; j++){
        temp2 = a[j][i]/a[i][i];
        for(z = 0; z<matrixSize + 1; z++){
            a[j][z] = a[j][z] - temp2 * a[i][z];
        }
    }


}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    //check for args
    checkargs(argc, argv);
    int matrixSize = atoi(argv[1]);
    int threadNum = atoi(argv[2]);
    //memory allocation
    a = (double**)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double*));
    for(i = 0; i < matrixSize ; i++)
        a[i] = (double*)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double) * matrixSize);
    vect = (double*)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double));
    bvect = (double*)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double));
    temp = (double*)malloc(matrixSize*sizeof(double));
    for(i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < matrixSize + 1; ++j){
            a[i][j] = drand48();
        }
    }
    j = 0;
    j += matrixSize;
    for(i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i){
        bvect[i] = a[i][j];
    }
//generation of scalar matrix (diagonal vector)
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    for(i=0; i<matrixSize; i++){
        scalar = a[i][i];
    //initialization of p to travel throughout matrix
        ptr = i;
    //find largest number in column and row number of it
        for(k = i+1; k < matrixSize; k++){
        if(fabs(scalar) < fabs(a[k][i])){
            //k is row of scalar, while
           scalar = a[k][i];
           ptr = k;
        }
    }
    //swaping the elements of diagonal row and row containing largest no
    for(j = 0; j <= matrixSize; j++)
    {
        temp[0] = a[i][j];
        a[i][j]= a[ptr][j];
        a[ptr][j] = temp[0];
    }
    ratio = a[i][i];
    for(k = 0; k < matrixSize + 1; k++){
        a[i][k] = a[i][k] / ratio;
    }   

    threader  stuff;
    stuff.counter = i;
    stuff.matrixl = matrixSize;
    //printf("i=%d\n" , i);
    //MAKE EACH THREAD DO SOMETHING DIFF
    // parallelstuff(int i, int matrixSize, double **a){
    for(threadcount = 0; threadcount < threadNum; threadcount++){
        if(pthread_create (&workerThreads[threadcount], NULL, parallelstuff, (void *) &stuff ) != 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: consumer create problem\n");
            exit(1);
            }
        }

    while(threadcount != 0){
        if(pthread_join (workerThreads[threadcount-1], &retval ) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: consumer create problem\n");
        exit(1);
        }
        threadcount--;
    }
}
    //create matrix of n size 
    //backward substitution method
    for(i=matrixSize-1; i >=0; i--){
        for(k = i; k > 0; k--){
            a[k-1][matrixSize] -= a[k-1][i] * a[i][matrixSize];
            a[k-1][i] -= a[k-1][i] * a[i][i];
        }  
    }
    for(i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i){
        vect[i] = a[i][matrixSize];
        }       
    double l2Norm;
    l2Norm = L2(a, bvect, vect, matrixSize);
    printf("THIS IS L2 NORM: %f\n", l2Norm);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    delta = ((end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec) * 1000000u + 
         end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1.e6;
    printf("end time: %f\n", delta);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two codes as written are not equivalent. Observe the OpenMP code:

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static)
for(j = i + 1; j<matrixSize; j++){
    temp2 = a[j][i]/a[i][i];
    for(z = 0; z<matrixSize + 1; z++){
        a[j][z] = a[j][z] - temp2 * a[i][z];
    }
}
```

The combined `parallel for` construct in OpenMP is a worksharing construct, i.e. it distributes the iterations on the following loop among the threads in the team. Given the `schedule(static)` clause, the iteration space is split into `#threads` blocks and each block is assigned to a different thread.

Your Pthreads code does not share the work:

```
i = temp.counter;
matrixSize = temp.matrixl;
...
for(j = i + 1; j<matrixSize; j++){
    temp2 = a[j][i]/a[i][i];
    for(z = 0; z<matrixSize + 1; z++){
        a[j][z] = a[j][z] - temp2 * a[i][z];
    }
}
```

Given that the same `stuff` object is passed to all threads, they all receive the same value of `i` and `matrixSize` and loop over the whole iteration space, therefore the wrong results.

What you have to do is simulate what `#pragma omp for schedule(static)` does, namely make each thread do only some of the `matrixSize - (i+1) + 1` iterations. You should pass each thread a unique data object that contains the starting and the ending iteration:

```
typedef struct threader {
    int start;
    int end;
    int i;
    int matrixSize;
} threader;

...

void *parallelstuff(void *args){
    threader *temp = (threader *)args;
    int start, end, i, matrixSize;
    start = temp->start;
    end = temp->end;
    i = temp->i;
    matrixSize = temp->matrixSize;
    double temp2;
    int j , z; //houssam
    for(j = start + 1; j<end; j++){
        temp2 = a[j][i]/a[i][i];
        for(z = 0; z<matrixSize + 1; z++){
            a[j][z] = a[j][z] - temp2 * a[i][z];
        }
    }
}

...

threader stuff[threadNum];
//MAKE EACH THREAD DO SOMETHING DIFF
// parallelstuff(int i, int matrixSize, double **a){
for(threadcount = 0; threadcount < threadNum; threadcount++){
    stuff[threadcount].start = i + threadcount*(matrixSize / threadNum);
    stuff[threadcount].end = i + (threadcount+1)*(matrixSize / threadNum);
    stuff[threadcount].i = i;
    stuff[threadcount].matrixSize = matrixSize;
    if(pthread_create (&workerThreads[threadcount], NULL, parallelstuff, (void *) &stuff ) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: consumer create problem\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

In theory, you could also let each thread know how many threads are out there and let it compute the iteration range itself, but that is complicated by the fact that Pthreads API lacks the equivalent of `omp_get_thread_num()`. There is an advanced trick that employs aligned memory allocation and the numeric thread ID encoded in the last bits of the pointer passed.